# How to change phpize to current version

Tags: php, homebrew, xdebug, pecl, phpize

I'm using Mojave OS X and I've been following these steps to install Xdebug through Pecl. I'm trying to set it up so I can use the debugger of PHPStorm.

http://www.devinbaldwin.com/2018/09/27/how-to-install-xdebug-on-a-new-mac-including-mojave/

This is my current setup:

`Xdebug installed: no
 Server API: Command Line Interface
 Windows: no
 Zend Server: no
 PHP Version: 7.3.6
 Zend API nr: 320180731
 PHP API nr: 20180731
 Debug Build: no
 Thread Safe Build: no
 OPcache Loaded: yes
 Configuration File Path: /usr/local/etc/php/7.3
 Configuration File: /usr/local/etc/php/7.3/php.ini
 Extensions directory: /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20180731`

I've followed all the steps but got stuck at installing Xdebug because I didn't have phpize.

I've installed the newest version of Xcode to create phpize, this worked at first, but I was having trouble appending the php.ini through PHPStorm because the file was read-only and I've thought of following another guide which talks about downgrading PHP to version 7.2 and installing Xdebug through that version, which is how this problem started.

When I tried to install Xdebug through Pecl, I've got this error.

`downloading xdebug-2.7.2.tgz ...
 Starting to download xdebug-2.7.2.tgz (230,987 bytes)
 .................................................done: 230,987 bytes
 69 source files, building
 running: phpize7.2
 sh: phpize7.2: command not found
 ERROR: 'phpize' failed`

At the sh, it never showed phpize7.2 before, it used to show phpize without the numbers.

I've tried to uninstall and reinstall homebrew and remove all php versions and installed the current php version as posted above.

I just want to know how I can revert phpsize to the current version. I've tried using PHP 7.2 but I still got the same error.

I've tried this guide since I'm using the latest PHP version, which is 7.3. 
https://sys.cuquejo.org/install-php-7-3-xdebug-on-macos-mojave-with-homebrew/

But I still get the same error.

In addition, when I typed phpsize I got this:
`Cannot find config.m4. 
 Make sure that you run '/usr/local/bin/phpize' in the top level 
 source directory of the module`

However, when I typed phpsize --help
`Usage: /usr/local/bin/phpize [--clean|--help|--version|-v]`

Typing phpize72 --help would only show this:
`-bash: phpize7.2: command not found`

I'm not sure why this happened but any explanations could help.

Comment: I've managed to find another way of installing Xdebug without PECL through this guide https://medium.com/@olivierpicault/installing-xdebug-on-mac-os-x-1f60df0a7317, however, I'm still curious to know why my phpize has 7.2 in it.

Comment: `phpize` is something which is needed to install the php module. Seems that PECL is trying to run `phpize7.2` for you and it fails